# Series eerily similar to The Grim Company by Luke Scull, with futuristic invaders with black and white magic that destroyed flesh and physical things?

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been spending far too much time trying to find this book series online to no avail. The series was definitely fantasy, possibly YA and possibly grimdark in nature. It was written in the 2000's and had 3 or 4 books in the series.

One of the books was an invasion of demons, some of whom were maybe flying and looked like manta rays? The last book was about an invading race of humanoids with superior technology and magic. They had two types of magic, a black one that dissolved anything living and a white one that destroyed anything non-living? I think?

They were an interdimensional race that travelled to new worlds to strip them of magic to power their machines. The entire premise sounds eerily similar to the Grim Company books by Luke Scull, which features demons in the second book and futuristic humans invading in the third, but I'm almost certain it's not the Grim Company. Did anyone happen to read a similar series around the early 2010s?

Comment: The Corean Chronicles by L.E.Modesitt? He also wrote the Saga Of Recluce books, which have black and white magic; based on order and chaos.